# Why does GCC fail to reduce a loop that increments two locations of the same buffer?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, optimization, compiler-construction

Here is a bounded loop that increments two locations of the same buffer.

```
unsigned int getid();
void foo(unsigned int *counter, unsigned int n) {
        unsigned int A = getid();
        unsigned int B = getid();
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ++counter[A];
            ++counter[B];
        }
}
```

According to the result from compiler explorer (https://godbolt.org/z/b1sjf5669), even at -O3 optimization level, the program still has a loop that involves `add 1` command.

In contrast, if `++counter[B]` is removed, the compiler can reduce the loop and optimize the program into `counter[A] += n`. (https://godbolt.org/z/4YoPcz5rT)

Why the compiler is conservative, i.e., not transforming the codes into `counter[A] += n, counter[B] += n` in this case?

I know that some alias issues would lead to the failure of loop reduction. However, there is only one buffer here and even `A=B`, optimizing the codes would not change the results.

Comment: Optimizations are a set of manually written rules for transformations, it might be that the rule for `counter[A]+=n` is not generic enough to catch this case. My uneducated guess would be that this rule requires no other access to `counter[A]` and maybe the compiler cannot "branch" and evaluate its decisions based on the relationship between `A` and `B`.

Comment: Yes, I think that optimization would valid; you could report it with the "missed-optimization" keyword on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ .  I don't think GCC is intentionally making sure all side-effects (even non-volatile ones) happen before a fault in case writing `counter[B]` faults or something, because that's not something GCC optimizations preserve in general.

Comment: clang has similar behavior.

Comment: The compiler has no way to know if A and B are the same index.  Granted, the compiler could check and branch, but that's not something they do these days.

Comment: @fuz: It doesn't need to check if it does two separate memory-destination increments without overlapping their loads and stores.  (That leaves it up to hardware to pipeline things if they're actually independent.)  The OP's `counter[A] += n, counter[B] += n;` is correct in C terms even in the A==B case.  (I'd have used `;`, but `,` is a sequence point.)

Comment: GCC and Clang will optimize away the loop for two increments in some cases where it knows they're to different locations, like `[A%4 + 0]` and `[A%4 + 16]`. 
 https://godbolt.org/z/PbeaW8nnE .  (+16 is the next cache line, but it doesn't know how `counter` is aligned so even `+1` could be into the next page.  And it chooses to use one 64-bit SIMD increment if we use `+1`, so as we expect it's assuming no UB, not preserving fault behaviour.)  But surprisingly `if (A==B) return;` doesn't help GCC or clang.  Clang even unrolls but sticks to strictly alternating.

Comment: @PeterCordes That would be possible, too, but would require the compiler to understand that the increments commute.

Comment: You don't need loops to see the problem, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66261 for instance. Note that an increment actually appears as 3 operations internally: read, add, write, which makes it harder to express such commutativity (although of course it would still be possible).

Answer (score 0):

As was already said in the comments, increment is actually 3 operands: load, add, store.

Conservatively, compiler is not allowed to reorder `MayAlias` memory operations.
To do what you want, the compiler must prove that the result of the computation does not depends on memory aliasing, which in general case would be non-trivial.

I think that the scope of this optimization is just too small for the implementation to be reasonable.